If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are anti-parallel, can a parallelogram be constructed using $3\vec a+\vec b$ and $\vec a-4\vec b$?

A parallelogram is constructed on $3\vec a+\vec b$ and $\vec a-4\vec b$, where $|a|=6$ and $|b|=8$, and a and b are anti-parallel. Find the length of the longer diagonal.

This question has a solution here and here.
But I wonder if any such parallelogram exists.
(Questions in both links are not same but similar.)

What does 'is constructed on' mean here?

@Paul I think they are saying the parallelogram is made using these two given vectors as sides.

The second link question is not the same. They give an acute angle between the vectors instead.

If $a$ and $b$ are antiparallel, then the parallelogram would be degenerate since it would lie in a line and be flat, unlike a traditional parallelogram.
But you could still do the same sort of algebra to find its "diagonal" lengths, even if not everyone would want to call it a parallelogram.
